# How to write routes with model inherit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model in app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

And I have another model in app/models/post/note.rb

```
class Post::Note < Post
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader 
end
```

In my controller :

```
def new
  @note = Post::Note.new 
end
```

My view form is :

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, :validate => true, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :title, :validate => {:presence => true} %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The error is `undefined method`post_notes_path' for #<#:0x007fe3d3fe2b08>`

I want to know how to write the correct route config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the url as an option to `simple_form`, to override the default path it uses. So if your `Post::Note` model has a path helper `note_path`, then this should work:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, :url => note_path, :validate => true, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :title, :validate => {:presence => true} %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Ref: [How do you handle single table inheritance in SimpleForm so a single helper handles all models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607016/how-do-you-handle-single-table-inheritance-in-simpleform-so-a-single-helper-hand)

Comment: Could you please check my another question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517879/does-my-practice-is-good-for-helper-testing-with-rails-engine